# Creating view that unions specific tables based on prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, union

I want to create a view that unions specific tables based on their prefix.
It's a database running on SQL 2008 server.

Tables are named as following:
`Table_XXX_13_1 ; Table_XXX_14_2 ;Table_XXX_15_3 ; Table_XXX_15_4 ...` etc

New view name: 'View_XXX_15'

How should i proceed? 
I want to filter on '`Table_XXX_15%`', tried to use *Select stuff*,
Please list some information, I'm new to SQL.

link to similar question: [I need to create a view that unions all tables based on their prefix (new tables added monthly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635295/i-need-to-create-a-view-that-unions-all-tables-based-on-their-prefix-new-tables)

**EDIT**
Following code doesn't work:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateView2015 
            @BaseTableName varchar(100),
            @View varchar(100),
            @s varchar(max),
            @v varchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        set @BaseTableName = 'Table%15%';
        set @View = 'View_097_001_test';

        set @v =
        N'(
          select stuff((
          select cast('' union all select * from '' as nvarchar(max)) + quotename(''CEE_097_001'')
          from information_schema.tables
          where table_name like @BaseTableName))
        )';

        set @s = 'DROP VIEW ' + @View;
        EXEC (@s);

        set @c = N'CREATE VIEW @View AS ' + @v;
        EXEC Sp_executesql @c, N'@View varchar(100), @BaseTableName varchar(100)', @View, @BaseTableName;
```

**OUTPUT:**
Procedure or function 'spCreateView2015' expects parameter '@BaseTableName', which was not supplied.

Comment: you already found a solution. what doesn't work?

Comment: See above, just edited it.

Comment: and what doesn't work?

Comment: Post the code you are using to call the stored proc.  You are not calling it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You missing quotation mark near `Database` and quotation marks should be added when setting dynamic variable `@v`.  Should be something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateView2015 
@BaseTableName varchar(100) = 'Table_XXX_15%',
@View varchar(100) = 'View_XXX_2015'
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

            declare @v nvarchar(max) 
            set @v =
            '(
              select stuff((
              select cast('' union all select * from '' as nvarchar(max)) + quotename(''Database'')
              from information_schema.tables
              where name like @BaseTableName))
            );'

        declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'DROP VIEW ' + @View;
        EXEC Sp_executesql @s, N'@BaseTableName varchar(100), @View varchar(100)', @BaseTableName, @View

        declare @c nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE VIEW ' + @View + ' AS ' + @v;
        EXEC Sp_executesql @c, N'@BaseTableName varchar(100), @View varchar(100)', @BaseTableName, @View           

END
```

Comment: after running the script, I got an error. See Output.

Comment: You need execute dynamic variables in following: `EXEC Sp_executesql @s, N'@BaseTableName varchar(100), @View varchar(100)', @BaseTableName, @View`